# Bottleneck in CA::Transaction::commit()

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-animation, xcode-instruments

When using the **Time Profiler** on interactions with a `UIScrollView` (containing many subviews) I often see `CA::Transaction::commit()` in the heaviest stack trace. What is this method and how can I spend less time in it?

[image: Screenshot]

My educated guess is that this is how Core Animation layers are sent to the GPU and that this could be sped up by reducing the dimensions of and/or number of `CALayer`s that must be rendered (i.e. the amount of data that must be sent to the GPU).

Comment: Try you explicitly use CALayers inside your UIViews?

Comment: Can you share code with your UIScrollView initialising & interaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess could be correct. Bare in mind that following things are typically also done in the `CATransaction::commit()`

- Layouting of CALayers: layoutSublayers, preferredFrameSize, CALayoutManager
- all `CAAction`s
- sometimes also the rendering of the various filter-properties of a CALayer
- probably the layouting of the subviews in your scroll-view